# Returning an Array

Tags: java, arrays

I am new to programming and Java and trying to write a program which takes two arrays as input and reports back their sum. I want to do this by creating a class which takes two arrays as constructor inputs and then creating a method that adds them together and a method which prints out this new sum array.

Here is my class:

```
public class test1 {
    int [] a;
    int [] b;
    int [] final23;

    public test1 (int x [], int y [])
    {
        int [] a = x;
        int [] b = y;
    }

    public int [] sum(int [] x, int[] y)
    {
    int [] a = x;
    int [] b = y;
    for (int i = 0; i < Math.min(x.length, y.length); i++)
    {
        final23 [0]=x[0] + y[0] ;

    }
    return final23;
    }

    public void print()
    {
    for (int i = 0; i < final23.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(final23[0]);
    }
    }

}
```

Here is my main class:

```
public class main1 {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int l[] = {4,7,2};
        int k[] = {4,6,2};
        test1 X = new test1(k,l);

        X.sum(k,l);
        X.print();
    }
}
```

I keep getting an error when I run this through:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at test2.sum(test2.java:17)
>     at main1.main(main1.java:8)

I guess what I really want is for my `sum` method to take a `test1` object as input. However, I don't know how to do this.

Comment: What error? A complier error? A runtime error message? Or that the output of the program is wrong?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at test2.sum(test2.java:17)
 at main1.main(main1.java:8)

Comment: Not a bad first attempt.  One thing, you use capitals for classes (like Test1) but lower case for instance variables (like x)--I mean you can do whatever you want, but that's the accepted pattern.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your variable final23 is never initialized.
In java you have to initialize an array before using it. Either you do it during the declaration (like you did with k and l) or you have to do it later with a new `arrayType[arraySize];`

---

Here are the way an array can be declared/initialized.

```
int[] iArray = {1, 2, 3}; //Declaration, Initialization, set values


int[] iArray; //Declaration
iArray = new int[3]; //Initialization
iArray[0] = 1; //Set value

int[] iArray; //Declaration
iArray = new Array[3]{1, 2, 3}; // Initialization and set values
```

You can of course for the two last sample put the initialization on the same line that the declaration.

---

Try this (cleaned) code :

```
public class test1 {
    int[] final23;

    public int[] sum(int[] x, int[] y) {
        final23 = new int[Math.min(x.length, y.length)];
        for (int i = 0; i < final23.length; i++) {
            final23[i] = x[i] + y[i];

        }
        return final23;
    }

    public void print() {
        for (int aFinal23 : final23) {
            System.out.println(aFinal23);
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int l[] = {4, 7, 2};
        int k[] = {4, 6, 2};
        test1 x = new test1();

        x.sum(k, l);
        x.print();
    }
}
```

---

**Resources :**

- [Oracle.com - Arrays](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)
- [JLS - Array Initializers](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/arrays.doc.html#11358)
- [JLS - Array Creation Expressions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/expressions.doc.html#46168)

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to take a long shot here

```
 public int [] sum(int [] x, int[] y)
    {
    int [] a = x;
    int [] b = y;
    for (int i = 0; i < Math.min(x.length, y.length); i++)
    {
        final23 [0]=x[0] + y[0] ;

    }
    return final23;
    }
```

As a side comment, I'm guessing that you want to add all of the elements of the vector, not just the first. Change your for-loop body to:

```
 final23 [i]=x[i] + y[i] ;
```

What's final23? Where is it created?

Try adding this to your constructor

```
public test1 (int x [], int y [])
    {
        int [] a = x;
        int [] b = y;
        this.final23 = new int[Math.min(a.length, b.length)];
    }
```

Now final23 is defined and created, and you can use it in your class.

Answer (score 1):

If you supply `test1` with arrays in the ctor, you don't need them in the sum method, just use the ones you have in the class already:

```
public int [] sum()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < Math.min(x.length, y.length); i++)
  {
      final23 [i]=a[i] + b[i] ;
  }
  return final23;
}
```

You also had an error in the sumation, you didn't use the iteration variable, you also need to initialize `final23` in the ctor.

Answer (score 1):

You have to initialize final23 array before putting elements in it (on line 17).

```
    **final23 = new int[Math.min(x.length, y.length)];**
    for (int i = 0; i < Math.min(x.length, y.length); i++)
    {
        final23 [0]=x[0] + y[0] ;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I see a couple of things to point out here.

```
    public test1 (int x [], int y [])
    {
        int [] a = x;
        int [] b = y;
    }
```

First of all, remember that each `test1` object - that is, each instance of your `test1` class - has variables named `a` and `b`. I'm guessing that in the constructor, you want to take the arrays `x` and `y` which were passed as parameters and store them into `a` and `b` of the object. To do that, all you have to do is write

```
a = x;
b = y;
```

You don't have to write `int[]` again, not when you just want to access an existing array-type variable. You only write that when you're *creating* a *new* array-type variable. In this case, when Java sees that you've written `int[] a` in the constructor, it thinks you want to create yet another array-type variable named `a`, separate from the one in the `test` instance, and that's the one that gets set equal to `x`. The thing is, that local variable gets lost at the end of the constructor. So you're left with a `test1` instance that has variables `a` and `b` that still refer to nothing, i.e. they're `null`.

By the way, since you're going to be using the array `final23` later on, you should initialize it. Right now, it refers to `null` because you never set it to equal anything else. You'll need to create a new array and store it in that variable in order to be able to use it later on. So put this line in your constructor:

```
    final23 = new int[Math.min(a.length, b.length)];
```

That creates the new array with a length equal to the shorter of the two arrays passed in.

Moving on:

```
    public int [] sum(int [] x, int[] y)
    {
        int [] a = x;
        int [] b = y;
```

In this bit of code, you have the same issue as in the constructor: you create two *new* array-type variables `a` and `b` that get used instead of the ones in the `test1` object. I don't think that's what you meant to do. So I'd say get rid of those last two lines entirely.

There's another problem, though: if you think about it, you still have two arrays stored in the `test1` object. Assuming you've fixed your constructor, those are the same two arrays that were passed to the constructor. And now you're getting two *new* arrays under the names `x` and `y`. So you have four arrays total. Which ones did you want to sum up? I'm guessing that you meant to sum the two arrays that were passed to the constructor. In that case, your `sum` method doesn't need to - and shouldn't - accept more arrays as parameters. Get rid of the parameters `x` and `y`, so your `sum` method just looks like

```
    public int [] sum()
    {
```

Now you have to change the rest of that method to use `a` and `b`, starting with the `for` loop. Change its opening line to this:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < Math.min(a.length, b.length); i++)
        {
```

I notice you were wondering how to get your `sum` method to take an instance of `test1`. Well, in a way it actually does. There's a special hidden parameter passed to all methods (except `static` ones) that contains the object the method was called on - in fact, using your main program as an example you could kind of think of `X.sum(k,l);` as actually calling `test1.sum(X,k,l);`, where `X` is the special hidden parameter. You can access it inside the method using the name `this` (so you could write `this.a` instead of just `a`), but Java is generally smart enough to do that for you.

In the body of the `for` loop, you have another problem. What you want to do is add up corresponding elements of the arrays, i.e. `a[0] + b[0]` goes into `final23[0]`, `a[1] + b[1]` goes into `final23[1]`, and so on. But inside the for loop, you only ever add up element 0 of each array. You need to use the loop index variable `i`, because that runs through all the values from `0` to the length of the shorter array minus 1.

```
            final23 [i] = a[i] + b[i];
        }
        return final23;
    }
```

So the first time the loop runs, `i` will be `0`, and you'll set `final23[0] = a[0] + b[0]`. The next time it runs, `i` will be `1`, and you'll set `final23[1] = a[1] + b[1]`. And so on.

The same problem occurs in your `print` method. Each time through the loop, you always print out `final23[0]`, when you really should be printing out `final23[i]` because `i` changes each time you go through the loop. Change it to

```
    public void print()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < final23.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(final23[i]);
        }
    }
```

---

At this point your program should be working, I think, but there are still some improvements you could make to its design. For one thing, every time you create an object of `test1`, you know you're immediately going to call `sum` on it. So why not just put the summing-up code right into the constructor? That way you know that the sum will be computed right when you create the object, and you don't have to call `sum` explicitly.

Of course, once you do that, you'll have no way to access the array `final23` from your main class - except that if you want to print it, you can call the `print` method. But what if you want to write a main class that, say, adds up two arrays, and then adds the result to a third array? It'd be nice to have a way to get the result from the `test1` instance. So you can add an accessor method, possibly named `getFinal23`, that just returns the sum array `final23`.

In practice, this operation of adding two arrays would probably be implemented as a static method. So if you want, you could try starting over, and writing it as a static method. (Remember that a static method is one which doesn't receive a special hidden parameter) Inside the static method, you'd have to create the `final23` array, go through the loop to compute the sums, and then return the array you created. You'll need to enclose the static method in a class, of course, but that class doesn't have to have a constructor since you never really use it for anything. It'd look something like this:

```
public class SumClass { // pun intended ;-)
    public static int[] sum(int[] x, int[] y) {
        // you fill in this part
    }
}
```